# sftp,ssh hang from personal ubuntu to aws ubuntu ec2 but not putty on same box

Tags: networking, ssh, amazon-ec2, sftp

when using the command line ssh sftp applications from local ubuntu to ec2 ubuntu I periodically get hangs.

The weird thing is when using putty (from same linux laptop or different windows box (all same local network)) I don't see any problem.  I can provide more details if necessary, but is there anything obvious between the two implementations that might be causing a problem?

Answer (score 1):

No obvious implementation differences. Most likely it's a configuration difference, maybe related to ServerAliveInterval and TCPKeepAlive (ssh) or Seconds between keepalives and Enable TCP keepalives (PuTTY, in the Connection configuration).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  i will take a look and see if I can figure out what the delta is.